# In Ember.js Where do I put initialization code for a controller, tried routes setup controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, highcharts

I have been working with ember.js and highcharts. I found some examples but the simplicity of the examples has not allowed me to understand where I should setup the chart objects and render them.

I have looked at initializers. I understand the role of routes (I think), and how Route objects can maintain state.

I had an example and was trying to move my initialization code into a Route setupController function. Here is a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gregorydickson/as9dZ/

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    //These do not work here?????
    controller.createGraph('graph1', 'line');
    controller.createGraph('graph2', 'column');
   }
 });
```

where I was moving the code and it does not work (you can comment out the two calls in the Router and uncomment them at the bottom of the javascript to get it to run).

I plan on having a model that retrieves json from the server in an initializer but cannot get past this issue.

Comment: At the beginning I advice you to fix the errors, which you have in ember. (use developer console in the browser).

Answer (score 1):

**The root of the problem:** You're trying to render to the DOM before the route's templates have been rendered.

**In more detail:**

When interacting with DOM elements and/or the view template  (e.g. `$('#graph1')`) you should utilize the view layer. You're calling a controller method from the route and the controller is trying to target something in the view's template, but the view comes after the controller and the template is rendered after the view has been created.

Specifically, you should utilize the `Em.View` event `didInsertElement` or the `afterRender` hook of the `Ember.run` loop when doing stuff with your templates like targeting a selector. The exception is handlebars bindings, which update automatically.

For example:

```
App.MyView = Em.View.extend({
  doSomethingWithTheDOM: function() {
    this.$().find('#graph1').setChart();
  }).on('didInsertElement');
});
```

Or:

```
App.MyView = Em.View.extend({
  doSomethingWithTheDOM: function() {
    Em.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
      this.$().find('#graph1').setChart();
    });
  }).on('willInsertElement');
});
```

In this scenario, as you're binding data that may change I'd actually use a graph [component](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html) and bind the content like so:

```
{{render-graph content=someArrayOfData}}
```

**Rule of thumb:** Use the route for getting data from the store and setting it as a property on the controller (by default the route's model is set as the controller's `content` property. Use the view for interacting with the template and rendering childViews, etc. Finally, use the controller as the workhorse for everything inbetween (e.g. properties, saving, etc).

**Sidenote:** when overriding core object methods like `setupController` you should call `this._super(controller, model)` (or `this._super()` if there are no arguments) to ensure your Ember app does everything is should. Basically `_super` just calls the function that would have run if you hadn't overridden the method.